# detecting a specific string in a text file

Tags: c++

I have a big text file with html on it, and i want to add a space after every "`</b>`" (after every word in bold)

The text lenght is about 581 810

And i have no idea how to do this correctly, i wanted to try this:

1-Create a string vector named "v"

2-Get every single character of the text (don't know how to this, i can get line and word, but i don't how for get characters) in this vector (with push back and another string)

3- detect every "`</b>`" with a "for" loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 581810; i++)
{
    if (v[i] + v[i+1] + v[i+2] + v[i+3] == "</b>"){

      // add a space after </b> (don't know how to this)

    }
}
```

but i don't know to get every single character in my string vector, i know how to get lines, with getline, and words with ">>". I can't do this with words because html tags are sticked to the words

thanks

Comment: Do you have to use c++ ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you want to do this in c++ or are you just looking for a solution in general?

Comment: You need a pretty solution, that doesn't assume the characters to be only 581810.

Comment: i am doing this in c++ because i am learning C++, it's for training myself.

Comment: if using a linux OS you can use sed command (http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html) using system command line :http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/KZsyc6

Without doing anything fancy (regex, shell commands), you can do something like this:

```
const std::string bTag("</b>");
std::string line;
size_t indexOfBTag=0;
for( ... ) //iterate through your file, line by line
{
  //populate line with current line from file via getline, up to you

  //store position of the b tag into indexOfBTag and make sure that theres a b tag in your line
  //make sure to search starting after the last BTag found, or this loop will never end
  //however, if the index is 0 (meaning the first search), dont bother adding the size
  //hence the find(..., indexOfBTag > 0 ? indexOfBTag + bTag.size() : 0)
  while((indexOfBTag = line.find(bTag, indexOfBTag > 0 ? indexOfBTag + bTag.size() : 0)) != std::string::npos) {
    line.insert(line.begin() + indexOfBTag + bTag.size(), ' ');
  }
}
```